# Running store procedure using ef - not returning any results but works in ssms

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
Store procedure:
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserRecordGet]
                @Name varchar(20) = null,
                @ID int = 0,
                @Email nvarchar(50) = null
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT [id]
          ,[Username]
          ,[Password]
          ,[Type]
          ,[Role_id]
          ,[EmployeeID]
          ,[IsActive]
          ,[HomeTelephoneNumber]
          ,[Company_Alias]
          ,[AgentID]
          ,[LastLogin]
          ,[IsApproved]
          ,[LastPasswordChange]
          ,[FailedLogins]
          ,Application_Users.LockoutEnabled
          ,[OLBAccess]
          ,[MartinAccess]
          ,[MarbleAccess]
          ,[Email]

      FROM [Martin].[dbo].[Application_Users]
      WHERE
            ((@ID >0) AND id = @ID) OR
            ((@Name IS NOT null) AND Username = @Name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) OR
            ((@Email IS NOT NULL) AND Email= @Email)
    END
```

C#:

```
 public Task<MAUser> FindByIdAsync(int userId)
 {
     object[] parameters =  {
                                new SqlParameter("@Name",SqlDbType.VarChar,20){  Value = DBNull.Value, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input },
                                new SqlParameter("@Email",DBNull.Value){ Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,Size=50},
                                new SqlParameter("@Id",Convert.ToInt32(userId)){  SqlDbType.Int,Direction = ParameterDirection.Input}
                            };

     context = new MALoginContext();
     var user = context.Database.SqlQuery<MAUser>("exec dbo.UserRecordGet @Name, @Email, @Id", parameters).FirstOrDefault();
     return Task.Run<MAUser>(() => { return user; });
 }
```

But I get null returned from that method.

However the following returns a MAUser:

```
 public Task<MAUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
     {
         object[] parameters =  {
                                    new SqlParameter("@Name",SqlDbType.VarChar,20){ Value = userName, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input },
                                    new SqlParameter("@Email",DBNull.Value){ Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,Size=50},
                                    new SqlParameter("@Id",SqlDbType.Int){ Value=-1,Direction = ParameterDirection.Input}
                                };
            context = new MALoginContext();    
         var user = context.Database.SqlQuery<MAUser>("exec dbo.UserRecordGet @Name, @Email, @Id", parameters).FirstOrDefault();
         return Task.Run<MAUser>(() => { return user; });
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nobody else has spotted my mistake I presume.

The clue is in the store prodcedure. I had the parameters the wrong way round. what an idiot.

I spent many many hours on that GRRRRRRR!!